# How to settext TextView in group in ExpandableListView

Tags: java, android, expandablelistview, expandablelistadapter

What I want to do is, when I click the child in ExpandableListView it will change the parent(groupView) according to a selected child. In short, this is like a `<select><option/></select>` in HTML.

**This is the childView**

```
public View getChildView(int groupPosition, final int childPosition,
                         boolean isLastChild, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {


    final String childText = (String) getChild(groupPosition, childPosition);

    if (convertView == null) {
        LayoutInflater inflater= (LayoutInflater) this._context
                .getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
        convertView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.list_item, null);
    }

    convertView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            Log.i("Onclick CHild: ", childText);

            //This is where I want to setText the View of its groupView
        }
    });

    TextView txtListChild = (TextView) convertView
            .findViewById(R.id.listItem);

    txtListChild.setText(childText);
    return convertView;
}
```

**This is the groupView**

```
@Override
public View getGroupView(int groupPosition, boolean isExpanded,
                         View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    String headerTitle = (String) getGroup(groupPosition);

    if (convertView == null) {
        LayoutInflater infalInflater = (LayoutInflater) this._context
                .getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
        switch(groupPosition){
            case 0:{
                convertView = infalInflater.inflate(R.layout.type_header, null);
                break;
            }
            case 1:{
                convertView = infalInflater.inflate(R.layout.make_header, null);
                break;
            }
            case 2:{
                convertView = infalInflater.inflate(R.layout.model_header, null);
                break;
            }
            case 3:{
                convertView = infalInflater.inflate(R.layout.engine_header, null);
                break;
            }
            case 4:{
                convertView = infalInflater.inflate(R.layout.weight_header, null);
                break;
            }
        }
    }


    Holder holder = new Holder(this._context);
    holder.title = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.headerTitle);
    holder.title.setText(headerTitle);

    return convertView;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

public View getGroupView(int groupPosition, boolean isExpanded,View convertView,ViewGroup parent) {
    String headerTitle = (String) getGroup(groupPosition);

```
if (convertView == null) {
    LayoutInflater infalInflater = (LayoutInflater) this._context
            .getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
    switch(groupPosition){
        case 0:{
            convertView = infalInflater.inflate(R.layout.type_header, null);
            break;
        }
        case 1:{
            convertView = infalInflater.inflate(R.layout.make_header, null);
            break;
        }
        case 2:{
            convertView = infalInflater.inflate(R.layout.model_header, null);
            break;
        }
        case 3:{
            convertView = infalInflater.inflate(R.layout.engine_header, null);
            break;
        }
        case 4:{
            convertView = infalInflater.inflate(R.layout.weight_header, null);
            break;
        }
    }
}
Holder holder = new Holder(this._context);
holder.title = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.headerTitle);
holder.title.setText(getGroup(groupPosition));
return convertView;}
```

Please use this code.